# React-Native Keyboard error

Tags: ios, react-native

For any input this pops up:

[image]

I have checked the github for this issue but nothing seems to be working.
I have used Keyboard Aware but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that is triggering this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using native-base and react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view components. If that is your case, maybe this https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/25 and this https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/61 might help you.